# Not able to get Multiple Node Webkit apps started: Broken pipe error

Tags: node-webkit

For some reason, I am not able to start the same node-webkit application more than once. If I try to, I get the following error:

```
[37518:0100/000000:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(546)] write: Broken pipe
```

Has anyone been able to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. Added

```
"single-instance": false
```

to the package.json file. Now I am able to start several instances of the same app.